Importing GRASS GIS into another Python Environment on Windows
How do I access GRASS GIS modules from inside a brand new Python environment such as venv, pipx, uv, pixi, or just regular Python?

I've installed GRASS 8.4 through QGIS, but it is sitting in C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS 8.4\
Adding "C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS 8.4" to your "Path" environment variable on Windows will make this easier.
You can start a GRASS GIS 8.4 session on Windows by opening Windows Powershell and running "C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS 8.4\grass84.bat" and that will open up the GUI for GRASS and you can run grass modules like you can on Linux or Mac.
Activate your Python environment add whatever packages you want, as long as you include the following you can access any grass modules through their Python interfaces.
import sys
import subprocess
sys.path.append(subprocess.check_output(["C:\\Program Files\\GRASS GIS 8.4\\grass84.bat", "--config", "python_path"], text=True, shell=True).strip())
import grass.script as gs

If you added "C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS 8.4" to your Path environment variable you can shorten it to:
import sys
import subprocess
sys.path.append(subprocess.check_output(["grass84", "--config", "python_path"], text=True, shell=True).strip())
import grass.script as gs

Perhaps put it in a jupyter notebook with grass.jupyter.
You can install pip, scikit-learn, and other packages through the OSGeo4W installer as described on the OSGeo Discourse so they can be accessible inside GRASS GIS’s interactive shell.
